# android design not aligning right

Tags: android

I have the following problem:

when i want to place an LinearLayout into an relativelayout it won't align to left or right it still has some white space.

**Solution**

check padding from relative layout

Comment: do height match_parent !!!

Comment: paste your xml for detailed help

Comment: @MarkoLazić     Added xml

Comment: you can use the frame layout.. and just click and drag the views to fix it to where you want..

Comment: @amal          Same problem.. still a lot of spacing between the borders of the screen

Comment: is it looking as u designed in the graphical layout... make sure u selected the tablet display in the graphical layout..or you may have just changed it to landscape mode

Comment: @amal            Hmm i'm sure that i have selected 10'1 inch tablet when designing, if you mean that. And yeah because the app should only support landscape, i don't want to use portrait

Comment: found the answer.. how stupid..

Comment: it might be because of your first linearlayout in relative layout is `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` try and remove this property also what are padding values in your parent layout

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do, is change the width attribute of your top RelativeLayout from "match_parent" to "fill_parent".

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
...
```

Second, I change the width attribute of your Left Layout, to "match_parent"

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
...
```